# A full verion of the periodic table (For computer game)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am looking for a full set of data on every element on the periodic table. (and if possible those only speculated about)

When I say full I mean everything. Electron configurations, Valence electrons, melting point, Atomic mass, Isotopes and what they decay into and all the rest.

Is there such a database anywhere?

Comment: My nephew knew the first 150 or so first-series Pokemon, and all about them, by the time he was 7. I often thought that if there was a game with characters named after the chemical elements, he'd be streets ahead by the time he went to senior school. I hope your game will be as exciting (and profitable) as Pokemon!

Comment: It is answered [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all these information on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).  You can use the website directly to obtain these information, and you can call their [API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) to directly fetch the data online from your own program.  Of course, you can also use Mathematica to write your program and query the database with [WolframAlpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html) function.

Comment: Learned the api in about an hour and now I can query their database from c#. This is just amazing. Thank you.